# Accessing A button in a Grid Control Prgrammically DevExpress

Tags: devexpress

I wanna enable/disable a button found in every row of my grid control. I am not sure how I can access it through code. I would think it would bein the GridView1 methods.....

Comment: Could you please explain how you added buttons to the gridControl rows?  Also, please explain why you need to access these buttons.

Comment: I added the buttons by creating a new column in the grid control and setting the columnEdit property to a simple button. I need to access the buttons enabled property to when the form loads based on a another columns value each row may or may not have the button enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the button (or better yet, the entire editing of a specif cell) by just handling the ShowingEditor event... You can then inspect the values of other columns and then cancel the editing of that cell depending on your wishes. Here goes some code for a sample program that shows you exactly how to do that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid;

namespace GridButtonDisable
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class MyData
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public bool Even { get { return Number % 2 == 0; } }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<MyData> List = new List<MyData>
        {
            new MyData() { Number = 1 },
            new MyData() { Number = 2 },
            new MyData() { Number = 5 },
            new MyData() { Number = 7 },
            new MyData() { Number = 10 },
        };

        gridControl1.DataSource = List;
        gridView1.ShowingEditor += gridView1_ShowingEditor;
    }

    private void gridView1_ShowingEditor(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        if (view.FocusedColumn.Name == "gridButtonCol" && 
            !(bool)view.GetRowCellValue(view.FocusedRowHandle, "Even") )
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

This is a pretty simple program. You must assume your button edit column is named gridButtonCol... I'm testing the value of the Even column of the MyData class I've created for this sample, you can do whatever you want and check whichever condition you like here.

If you set the e.Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs of the ShowingEditor event, the cell won't be editable and the button editor won't respond to user clicks...